# Screen status bar multiple lines

Tags: gnu-screen

I am using screen with several tabs open to separate my projects between them. However, when I open too many tabs they just appear off screen and I can no longer see them in my "screen status bar". I can still switch to them, but not see them in my list of windows. How can I make it so that my "screen status bar" will expand to two lines when necessary? I've gotten a `.screenrc` from a friend to start with which put me where I'm at, but I'd like to customize it to afford me this option.

Answer (score 3):

I turn off the status bar, myself, because that's not a pratical way to manage screen with 40+ windows.  Using Ctrl-A + " will open a list of all screens.  You can name individual windows with Ctrl-A + A.  I also use a customized .screenrc that, among other things, shows the Shell Title message in the Window listing.

```
# terminfo and termcap for nice 256 color terminal
# allow bold colors - necessary for some reason
attrcolor b ".I"
# tell screen how to set colors. AB = background, AF=foreground
#termcapinfo xterm 'ti=\E[?1049h:te=\E[?1049l'
#termcapinfo xterm 'Co#256:AB=\E[48;5;%dm:AF=\E[38;5;%dm:hs:ts=\E]2;:fs=\007:ds=\E]2;screen\007'
termcapinfo xterm* 'Co#256:AB=\E[48;5;%dm:AF=\E[38;5;%dm:hs:ts=\E]2;:fs=\007:ds=\E]2;screen\007:ti=\E[?1049h:te=\E[?1049l:XT'
termcapinfo screen* 'Co#256:AB=\E[48;5;%dm:AF=\E[38;5;%dm:hs:ts=\E]2;:fs=\E\\:ds=\E]2;screen\E\\:ti=\E[?1049h:te=\E[?1049l:XT'
# erase background with current bg color
defbce "on"
altscreen on
#hardstatus on
defscrollback 2000
multiuser on

hardstatus string "[%n%?: %t%?] %h"
windowlist string "%3n %t   %h%=%f"
```

Comment: Personally I'd rather stick with the key mappings and setup I already have. I wont need to manage 40 or more screens just about 15 so I would one more row to make it perfect!! Thanks though

Comment: I am using screen's default keymappings.  The only line I'd recommend above is windowlist. It will make the window list much more useful. The rest of that file does things like enable 256 color mode and enable XTerm titles.

Answer (score 0):

I have a hint about how to make it work: *screen in a screen*.

Draft of such a *<strike>solution</strike>* workaround:

- Your original screen with:

  - a *backtick* function that writes (into a file) the information needed to be shown in the second line
- New outer screen with:

  - a *backtick* function able to read the inner screen's information (the file)
  - a custom config file
  - a different *prefix* (that is never used in the inner screen)
  - **optionally** for better user experience:

    - run the inner screen in first window
    - single window
    - will exit when inner ends